# How to Install Driver with a cat file?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, device-driver, signed

I have kernel driver. When installing on 32 bit systems and Windows XP and below, I had no problem and used SetupCopyOEMInf, but 64 bit drivers are required to be signed. I have signed it and I need to have a cat file with the driver copied somewhere on the computer, and this method of install doesn't work. How should I install it?

EDIT: Clarified the question.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

In Windows Vista and Windows 7 there a new utility for handling drivers setup call [PnPUtil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff550423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It handles exactly this kind of work. Just copy all your driver relevant files(*.inf, *.cat, *.sys) to a directory on the target computer and use `PnPUtil -i -a <InfName>.inf`

#### Note: You will need to be in an administrator context to successfully use this tool.

Comment: Just so it is clear, I received an error stating the INF passed in was invalid until I ran the CMD as an Administrator, so do not expect some kind of access denied error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get an [Authenticode](https://www.verisign.com/code-signing/microsoft-authenticode/) signature, create a catalog file, and sign it with that. Microsoft decided that, for 64-bit systems, it will require the driver to come untampered from the vendor, by checking it signature.

(Note: This is **not** the same as WHQL, which tests the *quality* of the driver. Authenticode merely indicates that the driver hasn't been tampered with by some malicious user or virus; it doesn't say anything about what the driver does, so it's a relatively easy -- although pricey -- signature to obtain.)

Another solution is [test-signing](https://blogs.technet.com/b/tristank/archive/2007/01/30/test-signing-x64-drivers.aspx), if you don't plan on redistributing your program.
https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dd919230.aspx