# Script to install a driver

Tags: windows, installation, device-driver

There are problems in Windows 7 with device driver which should be installed and manufacturer has no real setup.

The needed files are on CD. But when device is connected, the device manager does not find the driver files. When searching manually for the driver files all is working well like it should.

I am .Net developer and now I need any batch or application or system I can use to install this driver on users computer.

```
12.03.2013  20:09           163'384 Cam1394ab_proppage_x64.dll
12.03.2013  20:09             6'138 Cam1394ab_x64.cat
12.03.2013  20:09             9'934 Cam1394ab_x64.inf
12.03.2013  20:09           169'016 Cam1394ab_x64.sys
12.03.2013  20:09            13'477 CamDriver1394.cat
12.03.2013  20:09            19'491 CamDriver1394.inf
12.03.2013  20:09            42'496 CamDriver1394.sys
12.03.2013  20:09            19'588 CamDriver1394_u.inf
12.03.2013  20:09            45'568 CamDriver1394_x64.sys
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PnpUtil solution works:

[How to Install Driver with a cat file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631789/how-to-install-driver-with-a-cat-file)

[image: PnpUtil]